# hokuyo node laser message publishing

Tags: ros, laserscan, hokuyo-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,
I am trying to publish the data of the laser scans of Hokuyo node.

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h"

void scanValues(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan laser)
{
    ROS_INFO("size[%d]: ", laser.intensities.size());
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<laser.intensities.size();i++)
    {
        intensities[i] = laser.intensities[i];
        ROS_INFO("intens[%f]: ", intensities[i]);

    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "hLaserReader");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Subscriber hokuyoSubscriber = n.subscribe("/scan", 1, scanValues);
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

this is the code, but i am getting this error

In function ‘void scanValues(sensor_msgs::LaserScan)’:
x.cpp:10:9: error: ‘intensities’ was not declared in this scope

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12371/hokuyo-node-laser-message-publishing/) by [searchrescue](https://answers.ros.org/users/1542/searchrescue/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2011-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It should be laser.intensities instead of intensities...

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This code works correctly.
My mistake was in CMakeLists.txt file.
I put **rosbuild_add_executable(hLaser_node src/hLaserReader.cpp)** very top of the file. Now that i moved this line to the bottom.
Now it works.
thanks.

---

Originally posted by [searchrescue](https://answers.ros.org/users/1542/searchrescue/) with karma: 50 on 2011-12-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1